# Using CreateTable<T>(CreateFlags.FullTextSearch4) doesn't auto increment PK

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, fts4

I'm using Xamarin on Visual Studio 2015 with this SQLite Plugin: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

Here's my algorithm and explanation of the problem:

```
public class MyModel
{
     [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
     public int _id { get; set; }
     public string bla { get; set; }
     public string ble { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Then:

```
conn.CreateTable<MyModel>(CreateFlags.FullTextSearch4);

var item = new MyModel();
var insertCount = conn.Insert(item);
```

The code above returns 1 for the insertCount and item._id is always updated as it should.
But when I later query the table, the _id is always 0 for all rows. For instance:

```
var tokens = mySearchBar.Text;
string query = "SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE MyModel MATCH '" + tokens + "'";
List<MyModel> result = conn.Query<MyModel>(query);
```

This seems to work but feels not right, it doesn't seem to be returning all possible result. But the main problem is that it's returning 0 for every _id. And I can check it out with:

```
var bli = conn.Query<MyModel>("SELECT * FROM MyModel");
```

All rows _id are 0. Any idea why and how can I fix it?

I have no problems if I create the table without the fts4 flag. But then I can't do the MATCH search.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Full Text Search Table](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html), mainly known as Virtual Table, are extension modules that allows users to create special tables with a built-in full-text index.

It ignores everything but the column names (e.g. auto increment, primary key, unique, and even Integer). Everything to an FTS table is just text.
This table has a privaterow called `rowid`. It behaves in the same way as the `rowid` column of an ordinary SQLite table, except that the values stored in the rowid column of an FTS table remain unchanged.

The only way to get and id from a selected row is by doing:

```
select rowid,* from thetable
```

If you try to do this in a common SQLite-net query, **you will not get the rowid**.

SQLite table scheme:

[image]

**Possible solutions:**

1 - In your case I don't know if you really need the Id. But you could remove it it, if it doesn't matter for the query (yes i know you posted in the question).

2 - You just can add a new column and place there some information that identifies the row, when inserting it.

3 - SQLite-net don't allow you to do a query and parse the result using a IDataReader. So you could use another [library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_4_using_adonet/) (android and ios) that allow to parse the query result to get the `rowid`.

4 - Don't use FTS table. Use a normal table and query something like this:

```
var query = conn.Table<MyModel>().Where(v => v.bla.Contains("mystring"));
```

Comment: Nailed it. My solution was to add a string id created by myself and set it as pk.